# Wordpress replace shortcode before plugin is initialized

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wordpress-shortcode

I use WordPress with Cornerstone and Essential Grid.
I want to setup a page template which has an URL-parameter, eg: `localhost/info/template/?id=1`
On this page I have an essential grid.

When `id =1` I want to show essential grid `mygrid1`, when `id = 2` I want to load grid `mygrid2`.

I tried to replace the shortcode with

```js
document.getElementById("myGrid").innerHTML= mynewGrid
```

But at this point, the grid is already initialized and I am too late. Also replace shortcode in functions.php (child theme) is too late.
So I made a new plugin. I had the intention that my new plugin loads before the essential grid plugin loads.

```php
    function createDynamicContent(string $content)
    {
    if (is_page('1209')) {
    Do the processing etc…
```

Load the new shortcode from DB, based on the url-parameter
then replace the dummy-shortcode with the real new shortcode using `$content`
the dummy shortcode is `mydummy`
the `$mynewgrid` is the string for the new grid `[ess_grid alias="berge"][/ess_grid]`

```php
    $newContent= str_replace("mydummy", $mynewgrid, $content);
    $content = $newContent;
    return $content;
    }
```

I added this function :

```php
add_filter('the_content', 'createDynamicContent', 10);
```

I also tried

```php
add_action( 'the_content', 'createDynamicContent', 100, 3);
```

When I set the priority parameter to `100` the dummy is replaced in the source but the grid is not loaded.
When I set the priority parameter to `1`, the page breaks.

Do I have a chance to dynamically replace the shortcode?